# Which method of icon creation should I prefer for Mac OS applications written via Qt

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt5

According to the official [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/appicon.html), the recommended way to create an icon for a Qt application is to use Icon Composer tool.

But as far as I know, Icon Composer was [deprecated](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59561/where-did-icon-composer-go-from-xcode) and new applications should use the iconutil instead.

Comment: Didn't you give the answer inside the question ?

Comment: @Thomas I wonder why the documentation tells about the deprecated way then

Comment: Maybe the qt team didn't updated the doc...?

Comment: @Thomas idk. Maybe there's another reason (for example, Qt doesn't work with .icns files generated by `iconutil` properly)